# Single sided buffers gives not only buffer on one side

Tags: qgis, line, buffer

I have tried to use single sided buffers to make buffer on one side of of a line. But the buffer is sometimes changing sides as shown below:

[image]

Must mention that the line is straight:
[image]

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 14):

Your line is made of several segments that have different orientations, so the "right" side of each segment is not always on the same side of the **complete** line.

To avoid this, you can first dissolve the line segments so that you are effectively buffing a single line. Alternatively, you can identify and swap direction of some segments.